# Replace n-th tab character with a string using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a line of items in Excel, and when I copy them in a textarea, I have several tab characters. I use this on purpose. Is there a way to replace n-th tab characters with a new line (each) and insert a specific word for each tab? Here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/kjuxk7m9/

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/\t/g, '\n')">
```

Basically, when I enter the following in a textarea:

```
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5
```

(between items are tab characters), my result would have to be:

```
Name1: Item1
Name2: Item2
Name3: Item3
Name4: Item4
Name5: Item5
```

Also, I might have more than one tab characters one after another. I would need them removed, so that I just have no empty lines after replacing them with new line char. Also, I would rather not use inline javascript, even if I did so far in the example.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Input text:

```
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4       item6   Item7
```

The expected result is:

```
LastName: Item1
FirstName: Item2
PhoneNumber: Item3
Nickname: Item4
AnotherRandomCategory:
Blog: Item6
OtherDetail: Item7
```

Item5 practically is an example of empty cell in my spreadsheet, and copying that would add an extra tab character. After having the above result, I would be able to delete that line, with a code, since that category does not have an item. The Items are examples, they are actually names, numbers, and other data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  var self= this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.value = 
      self.value.split(/\t+/)
      .map(function(v, index) {
        return 'Name'+(index+1)+': '+v;
      })
      .join('\r');
  },1);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gehx2yc5/)**

The timeout is needed, because the value of the textarea isn't updated until *after* the paste event.

The text is **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** on the tab character, and that array is updated using **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, then [**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ed with the newline character.

The regular expression `/\t+/` causes `split` to ignore multiple tabs in a row.

If you prefer to use the blur event, the timeout isn't needed:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('blur', function() {
  this.value = 
    this.value.split(/\t+/)
    .map(function(v, index) {
      return 'Name'+(index+1)+': '+v;
    })
    .join('\r');
});
```

---

**Update based on discussion**

The code below transforms this:
[image]

… into this:

[image]

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  var self= this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var flds=['LastName',
              'FirstName',
              'PhoneNumber',
              'Nickname',
              'AnotherRandomCategory',
              'Blog',
              'OtherDetail'
             ],
        order=[0, //LastName
               1, //FirstName
               3, //Nickname
               2, //PhoneNumber
               4, //AnotherRandomCategory
               5, //Blog
               6  //OtherDetail
              ]

    self.value = 
      self.value.split(/\t/)
      .map(function(v, index) {
        if(v==='' || index>=flds.length) {
          return '';
        }
        else {
          return index+' '+flds[index]+': '+v+'\r';
        };
      })
      .sort(function(a,b) {
        a= order[a.split(' ')[0]];
        b= order[b.split(' ')[0]];
        return a-b;
      })
      .join('')
      .replace(/\r\d+ /g,'\r')
      .substr(2);
  },1);
});
```

[**Working Fiddle #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7839y7sn/)

Comment: This looks like a good solution, however I just forgot to mention that Name1, Name2 were just random names. I actually have other categories for those values, for example: First Name, Last Name, Phone Number. I apologize for the confusion. The idea is to replace each tab character with a new line + a different name for each item. Except the first item, as it does not have a tab before it. I just need it's category before it.

Comment: This works regardless of what categories you use, except it always prefixes them with "Name1: " ... "Name2: " ... etc.  If this doesn't work for your "First Name, Last Name, Phone Number" example, could you update your question with expected results?

Comment: It works now, thank you! I have some other things to work on with this question. Is there a way to delete an n-th line after rearranging the text with the code you provided? Also, can I rearrange the lines so that for example "phone number: 123" appear after "nickname" (I would need this after running the previous codes, because in Excel I cannot modify the order)? Another issue would be that when I copy the line from Excel, it selects a lot of empty cells, at the end, which results having a lot of lines with "undefined:". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need the regex `/([a-z]+(\d+))/gi` on which we will be operating based on groups captured in our replace string.

We are first removing all the spaces and then using the above regex to replace it accordingly.

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('blur', function() {
   this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g,"").replace(/([a-z]+(\d+))/ig, "Name$2:$1\n");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLLvoog6/1/)

Comment: This works, however I forgot to mention that Name1, Name2 were just random names. I actually have other names for those values, for example: First Name, Last Name, Phone Number. I apologize for the confusion.