# Copying CSV data from a div to Excel sheet

Tags: html, css, excel, csv

Currently, if I have a `<textarea>` as follows:

```
<textarea>
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
</textarea>
```

and then copy and paste the contents into Excel. Excel will give me the option to paste from a comma delimited source.

However, instead of a textarea, I would like to use a div. I have tried the following:

```
<div style="white-space: pre">
    1, 2, 3, 4
    5, 6, 7, 8
    9, 10, 11, 12
</div>
```

Now when I try to paste into Excel it does not recognize it as being a comma-delimited source.

How can I format a div so that I can copy and paste pure text from it thus allowing Excel to recognize the delimited data?

Part of my reason for not wanting to use a textarea is that I am not wanting the data to be editable. The div also grows to the correct height of the content (which the textarea does not do.)

Comment: Is <textarea readonly> acceptable?

Comment: @Perhapsyouseethisname. No, as far as I know the readonly attribute will not automatically adjust the height of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I use LibreOffice and at least my solution works there. I copy the contents of the div, right click on the cell -> paste special -> unformatted text (ctrl + alt + shift + v)
If there is such an option in LibreOfice then in Office it should be;)

```html
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">
    1, 2, 3, 4
    5, 6, 7, 8
    9, 10, 11, 12</div>
```

You can also look at these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834896/replace-n-th-tab-character-with-a-string-using-javascript-jquery).

Comment: Does the option I posted above with just "pre" (not pre-wrap) also work with LibreOffice?